# How to add a column to an existing SQL output?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to Transact-SQL, assume I have a sql table

```
SELECT 
    Foods,
    Count(*) as total_count
FROM [SuperMarket].[dbo].[Grocery]
GROUP BY Foods
ORDER BY Foods DESC
```

output:

| Foods | total_count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 27 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 1 | 109 |
| 0 | 783 |

Is it possible to add an extra column in the existing sql output such as following. However, there is NO 'Name' in the original sql db.

| Foods | Name | total_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | meat | 27 |
| 2 | fish | 35 |
| 1 | fruit | 109 |
| 0 | pasta | 783 |

many thanks

Comment: I have a table, which only include customer info & Foods, which label in 0, 1, 2, & 3. but no 'Name' in the db. I would like to add an extra column to my output to show what 0, 1, 2, & 3, mean? I don't know it is possible or not. many thanks

Comment: that is a great idea. many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT 
    Foods,
    CASE
    WHEN FOODS = 3 THEN 'meat'
    WHEN FOODS = 2 THEN 'fish'
    WHEN FOODS = 1 THEN 'fruit'
    WHEN FOODS = 0 THEN 'pasta'
    END as Name,
    Count(*) as total_count
FROM [SuperMarket].[dbo].[Grocery]
GROUP BY Foods
ORDER BY Foods DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Slightly shorter syntax `CASE Foods WHEN 1 ... WHEN 2 ...`